# NIFI - Unable to Set Username and Password Windows

Tags: authentication, apache-nifi

I have Apache NiFi 1.16.3 downloaded and set up, but when I try to run the command for setting the Single User userid and password (`nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials`) using Git Bash in Windows I receive the following error:
`Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.command.SetSingleUserCredentials`

I have also tried running the workaround command by invoking the java jar explicitly with no success.

Does the capability to change the username and password not work on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-9500

> The following command can be used to call the Java class directly as a workaround:
> `java -cp 'lib/bootstrap/*' -Dnifi.properties.file.path=conf/nifi.properties org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.command.SetSingleUserCredentials username passwordpassword`

Answer (score 0):

`nifi.cmd set-single-user-credentials USERNAME PASSWORD` worked for me on windows. The password needs to be the lenght of 12 characters or more.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change password on windows cmd then use below script
nifi.cmd set-single-user-credentials USERNAME PASSWORD instead of nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials.
nifi.cmd is for windows and nifi.sh is for linux/unix